# Windows 7 applications run slower when not focused

Tags: c++, windows, unity-game-engine, directx-9

I'm attempting to run two applications simultaneously on windows 7, however, I'm finding that when I do this, whichever has focus runs at a normal speed but the other is clearly running at a far slower speed. (For reference, one is a unity application and the other is a C++ direct X application). Has anyone ever encountered something like this? Is there a way to allow both applications to run at full speed? The system ought to have the resources to run both, neither are very complex. When I monitor the system resources, etc, everything looks good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a task be completed faster if it is the active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153870/will-a-task-be-completed-faster-if-it-is-the-active-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows automatically offers less system resources to unfocused programs no matter their complexity or requirements. I don't believe you can disable that.

Answer (score 1):

That makes sense. I looked into a bit deeper and found that the Desktop Window Manager was the one causing the headache. I stopped the service, set the processor affinity for each application, and everything was golden after that.