# Any python code that is not in focus runs twice as slow

Tags: python, windows, performance, focus

Initially, I encountered this problem while learning YoloV8. At the start of training, while the window was in focus, each epoch took 7 seconds, however, after switching the window on the browser (no matter which window), each epoch began to take about 15 seconds. Moreover, if you split the screen into two parts browser / terminal, then even when the focus was changed, the execution time did not change.

Next, I decided to test it on a simple task. I started the Fibonacci calculation in cycle and encountered the same effect.

```py
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

def fibonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
 
 
for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    t1 = time.time()
    fibonacci(37)
    print(f'Time: {time.time() - t1}')
```

[image: I changed focus here. Example:]

I tried to give high priority to python/terminal/vscode processes, but it didn't help. Tried to run from terminal, jupyter, vscode, restart windows - no effects.

```
Win 11
Python 3.10.11
3090ti
13400F
32gb ddr4
1tb samsung 980
```

**UPDATE:**

Starting from the 12th generation, Intel has two types of core architecture - performance and energy-efficient. So the system works like an idiot - performance cores work only when focusing. Although they claimed that they have a special Thread Director technology in Windows 11 that manages cores very well but in fact it gives all the performance to the focus window

*To solve this problem, you need to run Vs Code (or any other process) as an administrator*

Comment: The *Windows scheduler* reduces the speed of background tasks to make foreground task more reactive/faster (and possibly reduce the energy consumption on some machines). A good exemple is games running in background or JS scripts of browser doing the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a task be completed faster if it is the active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153870/will-a-task-be-completed-faster-if-it-is-the-active-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the 12th generation, Intel has two types of core architecture - performance and energy-efficient. So the system works like an idiot - performance cores work only when focusing. Although they claimed that they have a special Thread Director technology in Windows 11 that manages cores very well but in fact it gives all the performance to the focus window

*To solve this problem, you need to run Vs Code (or any other process) as an administrator*