# Why does my Visual Studio Code notebook run much slower when VS Code is minimized?

Tags: python, windows, performance, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I own a Lenovo Legion laptop (16IRX8H - Type 82WQ) running the latest version of Windows 11 and have noticed when I minimize my VS Code, the python notebook I am running takes about 2x longer to complete. I am training an AI model on the CPU in Pytorch which can take hours to complete. I've noticed something is restricting the program from using more CPU resources in the background or when minimized, even if the foreground task itself requires almost no resources (like a notepad file).

I've tried the following:

1. Deleting all Lenovo software
2. Stopping NVIDIA software (even though I am using the CPU)
3. Changing power plan to highest performance on both Lenovo and Windows
4. Changing registry background task CPU limits
5. Changing task priorities to highest
6. Forcing the CPU to run at its highest speed with ThrottleStop
7. Changing system performance to prefer Background Services does not make a difference

None of these have made any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a task be completed faster if it is the active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153870/will-a-task-be-completed-faster-if-it-is-the-active-window)

Comment: No, I've already tried the recommendation they provide and it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.